# Route in Express not being found

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to building APIs with Node, Express and Mongo.

I'm trying to modularize my Express Mongoose API, but for some reason my code is not seeing the exported route.

When I use PostMan to test I get a 404 error.

All my files are located in the same folder

I have my main app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/guestbook');

var app = express();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());    

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));


    // changes it to use the optimized version for production
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });


module.exports = app;
```

I have my api.js file, which I reference in my app.js:

```
//DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


//include the routes file
var guestbook = require('./guestbook');

router.route('/guestbook');



//RETURN ROUTER AS MODULE
module.exports = router;
```

And finally my route, which is my guestbook.js file:

```
//DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


//GUESTBOOK END POINTS
var Guestbook = require('../models/guestbook')

router.route('/guestbook')

.post(function(req, res) {

    var guestbook = new Guestbook();

    guestbook.firstname = req.body.firstname;
    guestbook.lastname = req.body.lastname;
    guestbook.email = req.body.email;
    guestbook.postedon = req.body.postedon;
    guestbook.comment = req.body.comment;
    guestbook.rate = req.body.rate;

    guestbook.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Post created!' })

    });

})

.get(function(req, res) {
    Guestbook.find(function(err, guestbook) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(guestbook);
    });

});


router.route('/guestbook/:id')

.get(function(req, res) {

    Guestbook.findById(req.params.id, function(err, guestbook) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(guestbook);

    });

})

.put(function(req, res) {

    Guestbook.findById(req.params.id, function(err, guestbook) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        //USING OBJECT.KEYS TO UPDATE ONLY PARAMS PASSED
        Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function(prop) {
            if (typeof req.body[prop] !== 'undefined') {
                guestbook[prop] = req.body[prop];
            }
        });

        guestbook.save(function(err) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(guestbook);

        });

    });

})

.delete(function(req, res) {

    Guestbook.remove({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, guestbook) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted!' });
    });

});


//RETURN ROUTER AS MODULE
module.exports = router;
```

If I were to rename my guestbook.js file to api.js and reference that directly from my app.js, everything works fine, but I'm trying to use an api.js file in the middle, so I can better organize my code.

Any sage advice on how to fix this would be great!! Not sure what I'm missing that gives me the 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple issues:

1. You're using `/guestbook` too many times in your route definitions.
2. You haven't actually hooked the guestbook.js into your routes.

So, it appears you've created routes for:

```
/api/guestbook/guestbook/
/api/guestbook/guestbook/:id
```

You need to remove one of the intervening `.route('/guestbook')` you have.

That's why when you remove the code in `api.js` that is doing the extra `.route('/guestbook')`, then things start to work.

---

You have to decide where you want to define the `/guestbook` part of the path.  If you want it defined in `api.js`, then you can just leave that as is and in `guestbook.js`, change this:

```
router.route('/guestbook')
```

to this:

```
router.route('/')
```

And, change this:

```
router.route('/guestbook/:id')
```

to this:

```
router.route('/:id')
```

---

And, then to hook guestbook.js into the routing chain, you can change this:

```
router.route('/guestbook');
```

to this:

```
// hook up guestbook router
router.use('/guestbook', guestbook);
```

Comment: This is also true, but he's also not actuall using the guestbook.js file.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue, as I tried using that (after localhosl:3000) in Postman and I still get the 404. That being said, are you suggesting that I use a single route "/api/guestbook/guestbook/:id" and that should be good for all verbs?

Comment: @Paul - Yes, you are correct.  I've added the code to do that to my answer.

Comment: @cnak2 - You actually had two separate issues and need to fix them both.  I've added code for the second fix to my answer too.

Comment: @cnak2 - When I'm writing code, I don't start out with the most complicated router and file scenario like you have.  Instead, I bring basic routes up and running in an existing file and once they are working, I break them out into routers and separate files.  That makes it a lot easier to debug problems when you have something working and then make a change and it stops working and then you know exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Awesome! That worked and was very helpful. I'm going to study this and make sure I understand it. Thank you!  Also, thanks, Paul.

Comment: @cnak2 - If this solved your issue, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In API.js you're requiring the guestbook but never using it and just exporting the bare router that has nothing assigned to any actual handlers.